# HTTP запрос методом POST с помощью CURL

Tags: php, curl

Добрый день. Не могу разобраться с CURL

Использую api одного сайта. Передаю следующие параметры: url,id,hash

```
$myCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://site.net/api/create.php',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(/* */))
));
$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);
echo " Ответ на Ваш запрос: ".$response;
```

Встал следующий вопрос, как передать параметры на сайт url, id, hash через CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS и получить от него ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, создайте выше массив с данными

```
$data = array('url'=>$url,
          'id'=>$id,
          'hash'=>$hash
          );
```

Тогда строка в массиве CURL будет выглядеть так:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)
```

А так как я не знаю, что возвращает удаленный сервер, то смотрите какой ответ будет в переменной $response;

```
print_r($response);
```

Comment: Сервер возвращает одну строку. она одна на странице. Я не знаю как это объяснить, в php нуб.

Comment: так покажите, что возвращается в ответе :)

Comment: Я не знаю как объяснить, но запрос я посылаю так    <form     action="http://catcut.net/api/create.php" method="post">
 <p>гurl: <input type="text" name="longurl" value="https://vk.com" /></p>
  <p>id: <input type="text" name="id" value="256" /></p>
  <p>advsurfing: <input type="text" name="advsurfing" value="1" /></p>
    <p>Comment: <input type="text" name="comment" value="text" /></p>
  <p>hash: <input type="text" name="hash" value="3d9f6478ba650803011eebcc7bccb5b3301f7d26" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>

Comment: хорошо, это форма отправки чего-то. А потом где вы используете CURL ? Далее форму обрабатывает скрипт и AJAX посылает через CURL информацию на удаленный сервер? Что-то вы запутали меня